# how to use $sce in Angular directive

Tags: angularjs

Basically we would like to sanitize html data as soon I used $sce it does not work is there any alternate option to use instead $sce ?

app.directive('stack', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {

```
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      controller: 'StackController',
      scope: {
        onReady: '&?',
        onChange: '&',
        onDragStart: '&',
        onDragStop: '&',
        onResizeStart: '&',
        onResizeStop: '&',
        options: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller, $sce) {
  
        var stack = controller.init(element, scope.options);
       
        var serializeItems = function() {
          const data = [];
  
          $(element).children().each((index, item) => {
            const $item = $($sce.trustAsHtml(item)).data('_stack');
  
            data.push({
              id: $item.id,
              type: $($sce.trustAsHtml(item)).attr('type'),
              position: [
                $item.x,
                $item.y,
              ],
              size: [
                $item.width,
                $item.height,
              ],
            });
          });
  
          return data;
        }
  
      }
    };
  
  }]);
```

Thank in advance please guide

Answer (score 0):

Your injecting $sce in the wrong way:

```
app.directive('stack', ['$sce', function($sce){
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            ...$sce(your content) ...
        }
    }
 }]);
```

Notice that the module should be injected to the directive, as opposed to being injected to the link function.

Comment: Oh yeah thank you for this clue but it is not working with jquery  $(element).children().each((index, item) => {
            const $item = $($sce.trustAsHtml(item)).data('_stack'); 

any reason any advice you want to give me here

Comment: Attempted to trust a non-string value in a content requiring a string: Context: html

Comment: $sce.trustAsHTML takes a string, and returns a string, not an element

Answer (score 0):

I would use $sce with a wrapping function, just to render stuff in the View/HTML, so, in
the controller:

```
scope.trustAsHtml(str) {
   return $sce.trustAsHtml(str);
}
```

in the view/html:

```
<div>{{trustAsHtml(yourData)</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, So there is no view/html we have to bind it in jquery here $(element).children().each((index, item) => {
            const $item = $($sce.trustAsHtml(item)).data('_stack'); is there any alternate for this ?

Comment: item is a jquery object. $sce.trustAsHtml takes a 'string'. You could try item.html() to return the markup of the element as a string to pass to $sce.trustAsHtml

Comment: You mean like this const $item = $(item.html()).data('_stack');

Comment: I'm not quite following the scenario here. You say you have no view, yet you're using jquery to select elements, where from? Also, if you need to validate the element's HTML using $sce.trustAsHtml you'll have to convert your jquery elements to markup strings, validate the strings, then render them again into (not really sure where).

Comment: totally agreed, Okay I will give you one example hope you can understand the problem why I am using $sce

Comment: const el = this.$element.find(`#myid-${index}`); this is giving me Validate input from untrusted sources before it is used I thought we can fix it using $sce.trustAsHtml but it does not work, hence I am finding different idea to fix this do you have any idea ?